# How to tun two instances of keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

My requirement is such that i have an application authenticated via keycloak. Suppose if my current keycloak fails i need a second instance of the keycloak to run in parallel without any downtime.
Can someone provide some reference on how to create 2 or more instance and such that if one fails the one one can continue providing authentication

Thanks,
Radhakrishnan

Answer (score 1):

A clustered installation of Keycloak would allow for high availability and tolerate the failure of a single instance. The Keycloak and Wildfly documentation referenced below explain the particulars:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_clustering
http://docs.wildfly.org/18/High_Availability_Guide.html#JGroups_Subsystem